# Show Music Player On Bottom of Every View IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am creating an IOS app and I want to show music player instance on the bottom of every view.

Like this image
[image: See Music Player On Bottom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a base viewcontroller which will programatically create only bottom music player view, then extend all you viewcontroller from the base viewcontroller. thus all of your viewcontroller will get the same bottom play view.

Beware, all viewcontroller will different instance of the bottom view, you need to keep update all the bottom player view. A neat  way to do that is using `NSNotification`

Any change in the background image is listened by the @"backgroundImageChanged" `NSNotification` named. Any `NSNotification` fired inside the application is listened this observer and background image is changed accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. do you have any example ? em new in IOS..

Comment: I have updated the answer, have a look in the example. @NadanParinday

Comment: @NadanParinday How do you manage player in every screen , I need the same scenario in my application

Comment: @MaheshNarla i'm using [LNPopupController](https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNPopupController)

Answer (score -1):

It is a custom view built powered by AVPlayer. Look at the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/ and figure out how to build it?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. how can i manage it with ui ? i have multiple view controller how can i show player layer in all the view controller ??

Comment: You've to build it as a custom view with all the necessary controls for such as forward/backward, play, stop, pause and add or present to the view controller that you want to display. Those control will have the respective functions thats where you will make use of AVPlayer. Please see the example scattered in web.

Comment: i'll create custom view and put all the necessary controls in it. Suppose on the first view controller song.mp3 is playing then i click on button and go to next view controller then i want song.mp3 is continuous playing with seek bar ? how is it possible ?

Comment: check this image [Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9VGHH.png) player is show on bottom. and it always be on bottom when i go to next view controller.. have any example ??