# Swift 4: Add View on top of all controllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode9

Conditions:

- Swift 4, Xcode 9.3
- Target: iOS 11.3
- UI Done Programatically
- Using Constraints
- My Root View Controller is a Navigation

Situation:

I wanted to float an audio player that will be visible throughout the app.
I did an `AudioPlayer.swift` class that contains the user interface of the audio player.

`AudioPlayer.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FRadioPlayer

class AudioPlayer: UIView {

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let playerImage: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return iv
    }()

    let playerTitle: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.textColor = .darkGray
        l.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return l
    }()

    let playerSeriesTitle: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.textColor = .darkGray
        l.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return l
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setupAudioControls()
    }

    private func setupAudioControls(){

        let appDelegate = AppDelegate.sharedInstance
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "#EBE4D3")

        self.addSubview(playerImage)
        self.addSubview(playerTitle)
        self.addSubview(playerSeriesTitle)

        self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
        self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: appDelegate().rootView ).isActive = true
        self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        playerImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
        playerImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true

        playerTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        playerTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

        playerSeriesTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerTitle.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        playerSeriesTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerSeriesTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerSeriesTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y -= 150
            self.playerImage.frame.origin.y -= 150
            self.playerTitle.frame.origin.y -= 150
            self.playerSeriesTitle.frame.origin.y -= 150
        }, completion: nil)


        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.reloadInputViews()
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

How can I add this to the Root View Controller to stay on top in all view controllers that I have in my app? Wherever I navigate, the player must stay on the bottom part of every controller. As you can see, I need a reference to the rootviewcontroller to set the contraints for the `AudioPlayer` but I failed in so many attempts (like calling the rootviewcontroller using AppDelegate)

Comment: add it on UIWindow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777558/in-ios-how-do-i-create-a-button-that-is-always-on-top-of-all-other-view-control

Comment: can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646483/show-music-player-on-bottom-of-every-view-ios/38647816#38647816

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I  update it for you**

1. add singleton `static let shared = AudioPlayer()`
2. add  `public func showAudioPlayer ()`   --> to display Audio player
3. add as subview to `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?`
4. TODO- add HideAudioPlayer()

**Use like this**

```
 AudioPlayer.shared.showAudioPlayer()
```

Here is updated code

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AudioPlayer: UIView {


    static let shared = AudioPlayer()

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let playerImage: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = true

        return iv
    }()

    let playerTitle: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.textColor = .darkGray
        l.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13)
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return l
    }()

    let playerSeriesTitle: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.textColor = .darkGray
        l.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return l
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       // setupAudioControls()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

     public func showAudioPlayer (){
        self.setupAudioControls()
    }

    private func setupAudioControls(){

        self.backgroundColor = .red

        self.addSubview(playerImage)
        self.addSubview(playerTitle)
        self.addSubview(playerSeriesTitle)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self)

        if let  layoutGuide  = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.layoutMarginsGuide {
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor ).isActive = true
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        }


        playerImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true
        playerImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55).isActive = true

        playerTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        playerTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

        playerSeriesTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerTitle.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        playerSeriesTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playerImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerSeriesTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        playerSeriesTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y -= 150
            self.playerImage.frame.origin.y -= 150
            self.playerTitle.frame.origin.y -= 150
            self.playerSeriesTitle.frame.origin.y -= 150
        }, completion: nil)


        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.reloadInputViews()
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. This is the most detailed answer. 
But there's a catch, 
1) stretch to the side edges of the screen?
2) I'm using SideMenu from cocoapods, everytime I switch to another menu, my audio player disappears.

Comment: don't worry from this catch because your code excuted after window.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: I solved the edges of the screen using `safeAreaLayoutGuide` instead of `layoutMarginsGuide`.

Comment: Have you used [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)? Whenever I switch to another View Controller, my audioplayer dissapears.

Comment: will check for you may be you need to add change `Zposition`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170648/discussion-between-ruelluna-and-abdelahad-darwish).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show view in each view controller then as per view hierarchy you must have to add in `UIWindow`. `UIWindow` is base of all screen.

```
AppDelegate.shared.window?.addSubview(AudioPlayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your view to UIWindow.
I am doing the same thing with below method in AppDelegate.

```
var window: UIWindow?

func addPlayerViewAtBottom()  {
  var bottomView : PlayerBottomView!
  bottomView = PlayerBottomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 60, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 60))
  self.window?.addSubview(bottomView)
  self.window?.bringSubview(toFront: bottomView)
}
```