# Position element relative to the bottom of the screen in ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to achieve a result similar to Apple Music. When you open currently playing song it looks like it is a single view (content is positioned regardless of the screen size), but you can scroll down to reveal the details.

I would like to have a fixed page with elements positioned to the borders of the screen (a button at fixed distance from the bottom of the screen). When the user scrolls down, the details appear, much like Apple Music song page. How can I do that?

I prepared two hard-coded screenshots (they work only on iPhone 8 screen - smaller would hide the button and larger would reveal the red content).

If possible, I'd like to do it with autolayout only.

[This is how the screen should appear on every screen size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms9WU.png)

[This is how the app should behave when scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEdZS.png)

Comment: You might this q/a helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646483/show-music-player-on-bottom-of-every-view-ios/38647816#38647816

Comment: Thanks. This is something different, though. I would like the screen to appear like it was not a scroll view (with a button in fixed position at the bottom), but scrollable nevergtheless. Much like when you tap a particular song in Apple Music and you have volume and two other buttons at the bottom, but you can scroll it down for details.